# Can you use a private key on another host?

Tags: linux, ssh-keys

I am trying to clarify if an ssh keypair is secure in the sense that it can't be copied to another computer and utilized for a remote account. I thought they were machine specific and could not be used on another machine.

Comment: They're just files; you can move them around. It's generally a best practice for unique keys for different accounts/instances, though.

Answer (score 0):

As it is always with asymmetric cryptography, it has a key pair, consisting of private key which you keep secure, and a public key which you distribute.

Generally, the secret key is a client computer property, even more, each user should have a single unique key for each computer they use. It shouldn't be moved.

On the contrary to what was said in the comment above, not always SSH key is a file. For example, you can [securely generate and store your private key inside the PKCS11 token](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/configuring-applications-to-use-cryptographic-hardware-through-pkcs-11_security-hardening).

In case of SSH, your private key will allow you to authenticate to any system as the user, who deployed the corresponding private key into their `authorized_keys`. You may deploy many keys into the single `authorized_keys`. This calls for the following usage scenario (simplified): each machine you possess and trust should have its own key pair. For the machine to be able to connect to another machine, you append its public key to the desired user(s) on the target.

So, imagine you have a desktop, a laptop, a tablet (it is possible to install ssh client on e.g. iPad), and a bunch of servers which you want to control. You generate three pairs, for each personal computer, and each of those servers get all three public keys deployed on them. (Of course, when you use the token, you can simply take it with you and connect to appropriate computers in order to authenticate from them instead.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me and I wasn't aware of pkcs11 until now. So unless its utilized with something else we have to ensure people don't share their private key. I'm sure that there is further configuration but thought the private key was only able to be used on the machine generated on.

Comment: @JimmyWilkins: Or if you want a secret that is physically secure that is what smart cards are for.